# A question about potential difference across a membrane

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, biochemistry, ions, physical-organic-chemistry

Membrane potential of living cells arising from the difference of concentration of ions on both sides of the membrane, but why didn't someone use selective polymers as AEM (Anion Exchange Membrane) and apply pressure to cause accumulation of anions on one side of the membrane forming a potential difference?

Comment: I think it has been done...

Comment: @Martin-マーチン i didn't see anyone doing it

Comment: @mohamed, search Donnan potential and papers like these https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp0342273